# Подсчет количества number и checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Есть несколько чекбоксов, все выбранные чекбоксы суммируются. Но при вводе  количество этажей нужно: количество умножить на цену услуги, то есть `id="count2"` 
на `id="lift2"` и сложить с итоговой суммой. Чекбоксы можно выбирать одновременно.

```js
$('#count2').keyup(calculate2);

function calculate2() {

  $('input.a1').on("click", function() {

    var sum2 = 0;
    var sum3 = 0;
    // подсчет при нажатии на чекбоксы
    if ($("#lift").is(':checked')) sum2 += 200;
    if ($("#net_lift").is(':checked')) sum2 += 150;
    //подсчет количество этажей
    var count2 = $("#count2").val();
    sum3 = count2 * sum3; //нужно значение сложить к final_price_yslug и подставлять значение в #lift2

    $('#final_price_yslug').html(sum2);
  });
}

$('select,input').change(function() {
  calculate2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Подъём при присутствии лифта
<input type="number" id="count2" name="Количество2" value="1" />этажей
<input type="checkbox" id="lift" class="a1" name="Подъем с лифтом" />
<span id="lift2">200</span>
<br> при отсутствии лифта этаж
<input type="checkbox" id="net_lift" class="a1" name="Подъем без лифта" /> 150
<br> Итого:
<span id="final_price_yslug">0</span> руб
```

Comment: Вам нужны чекбоксы или радиобаттоны? Можно выбрать два чекбокса одновременно или не выбрать ни одного?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov можно одновременно выбирать

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что Вам нужно такой код

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var calc = function() {
    var price = 0;
    $('#elevator .a1:checked').each(function() {
      price += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    price *= parseInt($('#count2').val());
    $('#final_price_yslug').text(price);
  };
  $('#elevator .a1').on('change', calc);
  $('#elevator #count2').on('input', calc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elevator">
  Подъём при присутствии лифта
  <input type="number" id="count2" name="Количество2" value="1" />этажей
  <input type="checkbox" id="lift" class="a1" value="200" />
  <span id="lift2">200</span>
  <br> при отсутствии лифта этаж
  <input type="checkbox" id="net_lift" class="a1" value="150" /> 150
</div>
<br> Итого:
<span id="final_price_yslug">0</span> руб
```